# Quadratic Diophantine Equations in Polynomial Time

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, computational-complexity, factoring, quantum-computation

Considering the problem of finding lattice points $(x_1, x_2 ... x_n)$ that satisfy a quadratic law:

$F(x_1, x_2... x_n) = 0$

such that $F(x_1, x_2... x_n)$ is a second degree polynomial

It is known that for some simple examples such as:

$x_1^2 + x_2^2 = x_3^2$ (pythagorean rule)

$x_1x_2 = N$ (factorization of integers)

the problem can be solved in polynomial time on a classical or quantum machine. Is it possible that in general all single equation quadratic diophantine equations can be solved in polynomial time on a Quantum Machine? Is there any strong counterexample or example that sets serious doubt?

Comment: You mean finding one lattice point, or all lattice points? I doubt you can find all lattice points of $x_1^2+x_2^2=x_3^2$ in polynomial time :)

Comment: a lattice point. But would it be out of the question to find a general rule for all lattice points? The pythagorean triple does have a general rule involving only 2 variables.

Comment: There is certainly a lot that you can do with homogeneous quadratic polynomials, but I'm not sure there is a speedy way in general to, for example, determine if $x^2-Ny^2=-1$ has a solution? (There is an algorithm, but I think it can take a fair amount of time in terms of $N$.) Also, when you say "polynomial time," polynomial against what variable(s)?

Comment: polynomial with respect to the "size" (number of bits) used to represent the coefficients

Comment: If it is in terms of bits, then it is unknown whether $xy=N$ can be (generally) solved in polynomial time by a classic Turing machine. You can, of course, come up with the individual answer, $(x,y)=(1,N)$, but I think it is unknown otherwise.

Comment: xy = N is known to be solvable in polynomial time by quantum machines and Pell's Equation is solvable in polynomial time by quantum machines see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell's_equation#Quantum_algorithms

Comment: I assumed by your mention of classical machines that you were treating those as two different cases, since anything that can be solved by a classical machine in polynomial time can be solved in polynomial time by a quantum machine, I believe, so the inclusion of classical is redundant here.

Comment: That would be correct... but i wanted to emphasize that invoking quantum machines wasn't necessary until we got to the factoring problem or as you demonstrated pell's equation

Comment: wait does the -1 make a huge difference in solvability?

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking in terms of whether there is a solution. There is always a solution to $x^2-ny^2=1$. Pell's equation might be a good counter-example, since, according to Wikipedia, the solution can have $\sqrt{n}$ bits. As a rule, can quantum computers output $k$ bits in a lot less than $O(k)$ time? Turing machines, even non-deterministic ones, cannot, but not sure about Q-computing.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Quantum computers cannot output k bits in time $o(k)$ but there are more concise ways of showing the solution to a Pell equation.

Comment: @Charles Any references for that result? Certainly, you can put out the continued fraction coefficients, but that has as many bits, roughly, as the $x$ value. In any event, given that we are looking for a very general question about *all* quadratics, is it fair to have your program write out results in different formats depending on the different problems

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: See for example Lenstra's paper, http://www.ams.org/notices/200202/fea-lenstra.pdf